How can I simulate firefox animation behaviour on chrome when using calcMode="linear"?
I have two charts, the first one plots two functions, predators and prey. Each containing a circle with an animateMotion that goes along the function path.
The other chart is a phase curve generated by the functions. There is also a circle with an animateMotion that goes along.
Markers on the first graph should have constant speed with respect to X axis. The marker on the second graph should follow along the Y values of the first ones.
On firefox, using calcMode="linear" makes it work:
firefox linear animation.
On chrome, calcMode="linear" behaves the same way as calcMode="paced", so speed is constant along the curve:
chrome "linear" animation.
Including a somewhat 'minimal' piece of code, I kept the axis on so it's easier to understand what's going on.
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<div style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 450px; width:100%">
    <div id="prey_predator_chart" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div id="prey_predator_phase_chart" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
let prey_predator = {
    prey_color: "blue",
    predator_color: "green",
    phase_curve_color: "red",
    draw_graph: function() {
        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var margin = {top: 0, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40},
            width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var total_width = width + margin.left + margin.right;
        var total_height = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;

        // line graph
        var svg_pop = d3.select("#prey_predator_chart")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + total_width + " " + total_height)
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // phase graph
        svg_pop_phase = d3.select("#prey_predator_phase_chart")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + total_width + " " + total_height)
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


        var xDomain = [0,40];
        var yDomain = [0,30];

        var prey_c = {i_density: 10, growth: 1.1, death: 0.4}
        var predator_c = {i_density: 10, growth: 0.1, death: 0.4}
        
        var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height,0]).domain(yDomain);
        var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,width]).domain(xDomain);

        var yScale_phase = d3.scaleLinear().range([height,0]).domain(yDomain);
        var xScale_phase = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,width]).domain(yDomain);

        var eps = 0.0005
        var x_space = d3.range(xDomain[0], xDomain[1], eps)

        var prey_growth = function(current_prey, current_predator, eps) {
            return prey_c.growth*eps*current_prey - prey_c.death*current_prey*eps*current_predator
        }
        var predator_growth = function(current_prey, current_predator, eps) {
            return predator_c.growth*current_prey*eps*current_predator - predator_c.death*eps*current_predator
        }

        var preys = []
        var predators = []
        preys = [prey_c.i_density]
        predators = [predator_c.i_density]

        x_space.forEach((_, i) => {
            preys.push(preys[i] + prey_growth(preys[i], predators[i], eps))
            predators.push(predators[i] + predator_growth(preys[i], predators[i], eps))
        });

        var c_preys = d3.line()
                .x(function(i) { return xScale(x_space[i]) })
                .y(function(i) { return yScale(preys[i]) })

        var c_predators = d3.line()
            .x(function(i) { return xScale(x_space[i]) })
            .y(function(i) { return yScale(predators[i]) })

        var c_phase = d3.line()
            .x(function(i) {return xScale_phase(preys[i])})
            .y(function(i) {return yScale_phase(predators[i])})

        predators_curve = svg_pop.append('path')
            .attr('stroke', this.predator_color)
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('stroke-width', 2).attr('d', c_predators(d3.range(0, x_space.length, 1)));

        predators_marker = svg_pop.append('circle')
            .attr('r', 3)
            .attr('stroke', this.predator_color)
        predators_marker.append('animateMotion')
            .attr('repeatCount', 'indefinite')
            .attr('fill', 'freeze')
            .attr('calcMode','linear')
            .attr('dur', '10s')
            .attr('path', c_predators(d3.range(0, x_space.length, 1)));

        preys_curve = svg_pop.append('path')
            .attr('stroke', this.prey_color)
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('stroke-width', 1).attr('d', c_preys(d3.range(0, x_space.length, 1)));
            
        preys_marker = svg_pop.append('circle')
            .attr('r', 3)
            .attr('stroke', this.prey_color)
        preys_marker.append('animateMotion')
            .attr('repeatCount', 'indefinite')
            .attr('fill', 'freeze')
            .attr('calcMode','linear')
            .attr('dur', '10s')
            .attr('path', c_preys(d3.range(0, x_space.length, 1)));

        phase_curve = svg_pop_phase.append('path')
            .attr('stroke', this.phase_curve_color)
            .attr('stroke-width', 1)
            .attr('fill', 'none').attr('d', c_phase(d3.range(0, x_space.length, 1)));
        phase_marker = svg_pop_phase.append('circle')
            .attr('r', 3)
            .attr('stroke', this.phase_curve_color)
        phase_marker.append('animateMotion')
            .attr('repeatCount', 'indefinite')
            .attr('fill', 'freeze')
            .attr('calcMode','linear')
            .attr('dur', '10s')
            .attr('path', c_phase(d3.range(0, x_space.length, 1)));

        bottomAxis = svg_pop.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
        bottomAxis.append("text")
                .attr("class", "axis-title")
                .attr("y", 25)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .attr("x", (width+margin.left)/2)
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .text("Tiempo");

        leftAxis = svg_pop.append("g")
                .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
        leftAxis.append("text")
                .attr("class", "axis-title")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", -30)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .attr("x", -(height-margin.bottom)/2)
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .text("Densidad");

        bottomAxis_phase = svg_pop_phase.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale_phase));
        bottomAxis_phase.append("text")
                .attr("class", "axis-title")
                .attr("y", 25)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .attr("x", (width+margin.left)/2)
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .text("Densidad presa");

        leftAxis_phase = svg_pop_phase.append("g")
                .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale_phase));
        leftAxis_phase.append("text")
                .attr("class", "axis-title")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", -35)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .attr("x", -(height-margin.bottom)/2)
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .text("Densidad predador");
        diag_phase = svg_pop_phase.append('line')
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            .attr('stroke-width', 1)
            .attr('stroke-dasharray', '5,5')
            .attr('x1', xScale_phase(yDomain[0]))
            .attr('y1', yScale_phase(yDomain[0]))
            .attr('x2', xScale_phase(yDomain[1]))
            .attr('y2', yScale_phase(yDomain[1]))
    }
}
prey_predator.draw_graph();
</script>

Did a manual synchronization using keyTimes and keyPoints, and this does work for the first chart, but I don't know how to calculate the values for the second one.
This also is a bit cumbersome given how firefox just works.
        get_curve_points = function(curve, n) {
            var points = []
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                points.push(curve.node().getPointAtLength(i * curve.node().getTotalLength() / n))
            }
            if (points.length > n) {
                points.pop()
            }
            return points;
        },
        n = 50
        points = get_curve_points(preys_curve, n)
        xs = points.map(p => p.x)
        var min_x = d3.min(xs);
        var max_x = d3.max(xs);
        xs = xs.map(x => (x - min_x) / (max_x - min_x));
        keyTimes = xs.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x + ';', '') + "1"
        keyPoints = d3.range(0,1,1/n).reduce((acc, x) => acc + x + ';', '') + "1"
        preys_marker.append('animateMotion')
            .attr('repeatCount', 'indefinite')
            .attr('fill', 'freeze')
            .attr('calcMode','linear')
            .attr('dur', '10s')
            .attr('keyTimes', keyTimes)
            .attr('keyPoints', keyPoints)
            .attr('path', c_preys(d3.range(0, x_space.length, 1)));


        predators_curve = svg_pop.append('path')
            .attr('stroke', this.predator_color)
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('stroke-width', 2).attr('d', c_predators(d3.range(0, x_space.length, 1)));

        predators_marker = svg_pop.append('circle')
            .attr('r', 3)
            .attr('stroke', this.predator_color)

        points = get_curve_points(predators_curve, n)
        xs = points.map(p => p.x)
        var min_x = d3.min(xs);
        var max_x = d3.max(xs);
        xs = xs.map(x => (x - min_x) / (max_x - min_x));
        keyTimes = xs.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x + ';', '') + "1"
        keyPoints = d3.range(0,1,1/n).reduce((acc, x) => acc + x + ';', '') + "1"
        predators_marker.append('animateMotion')
            .attr('repeatCount', 'indefinite')
            .attr('fill', 'freeze')
            .attr('calcMode','linear')
            .attr('dur', '10s')
            .attr('keyTimes', keyTimes)
            .attr('keyPoints', keyPoints)
            .attr('path', c_predators(d3.range(0, x_space.length, 1)));


        phase_curve = svg_pop_phase.append('path')
            .attr('stroke', this.phase_curve_color)
            .attr('stroke-width', 1)
            .attr('fill', 'none').attr('d', c_phase(d3.range(0, x_space.length, 1)));
        phase_marker = svg_pop_phase.append('circle')
            .attr('r', 3)
            .attr('stroke', this.phase_curve_color)
        

        phase_marker.append('animateMotion')
            .attr('repeatCount', 'indefinite')
            .attr('fill', 'freeze')
            .attr('calcMode','linear')
            .attr('dur', '10s')



@Yogi I tried doing that and it worked for the first chart. But have no clue how to calculate it for the phase curve.

Not going to post this as an answer because it doesn't really answer your question.  But have you thought about using d3.transition to do the animation instead?  It'll give you much more control.  See here for a quick refactor of your code.

@Mark Amazing! This is exactly what I needed, fine grained control of the animation. Did some modifications of your code to avoid calculating position based on the curves and use the base arrays.
https://plnkr.co/edit/pikBUGHJhjAXxkUE?preview
I know it is not an answer to the question but it solved my particular problem.
If you post an answer I can mark it as such.

Great modifications.   You should post it as a self-answer and accept that instead.

Modified Mark's solution on the comment section to generate the animation based on current time.
This way I can synchronize every graph at the same time by scaling the current time against the x axis.


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<div style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 450px; width:100%">
    <div id="prey_predator_chart" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div id="prey_predator_phase_chart" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
  let prey_predator = {
    prey_color: 'blue',
    predator_color: 'green',
    phase_curve_color: 'red',
    draw_graph: function () {
        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var margin = { top: 0, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40 },
        width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var total_width = width + margin.left + margin.right;
        var total_height = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;

        // line graph
        var svg_pop = d3
        .select('#prey_predator_chart')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + total_width + ' ' + total_height)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

        // phase graph
        svg_pop_phase = d3
        .select('#prey_predator_phase_chart')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + total_width + ' ' + total_height)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

        var xDomain = [0, 40];
        var yDomain = [0, 30];

        var prey_c = { i_density: 10, growth: 1.1, death: 0.4 };
        var predator_c = { i_density: 10, growth: 0.1, death: 0.4 };

        var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain(yDomain);
        var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).domain(xDomain);

        var yScale_phase = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain(yDomain);
        var xScale_phase = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).domain(yDomain);

        var eps = 0.0005;
        var x_space = d3.range(xDomain[0], xDomain[1], eps);

        var prey_growth = function (current_prey, current_predator, eps) {
        return (
            prey_c.growth * eps * current_prey -
            prey_c.death * current_prey * eps * current_predator
        );
        };
        var predator_growth = function (current_prey, current_predator, eps) {
        return (
            predator_c.growth * current_prey * eps * current_predator -
            predator_c.death * eps * current_predator
        );
        };

        var preys = [];
        var predators = [];
        preys = [prey_c.i_density];
        predators = [predator_c.i_density];

        x_space.forEach((_, i) => {
        preys.push(preys[i] + prey_growth(preys[i], predators[i], eps));
        predators.push(
            predators[i] + predator_growth(preys[i], predators[i], eps)
        );
        });

        var c_preys = d3
        .line()
        .x(function (i) {
            return xScale(x_space[i]);
        })
        .y(function (i) {
            return yScale(preys[i]);
        });

        var c_predators = d3
        .line()
        .x(function (i) {
            return xScale(x_space[i]);
        })
        .y(function (i) {
            return yScale(predators[i]);
        });

        var c_phase = d3
        .line()
        .x(function (i) {
            return xScale_phase(preys[i]);
        })
        .y(function (i) {
            return yScale_phase(predators[i]);
        });

        predators_curve = svg_pop
        .append('path')
        .attr('stroke', this.predator_color)
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke-width', 2)
        .attr('d', c_predators(d3.range(0, x_space.length, 1)));

        predators_marker = svg_pop
        .append('circle')
        .attr('r', 3)
        .attr('stroke', this.predator_color);

        preys_curve = svg_pop
        .append('path')
        .attr('stroke', this.prey_color)
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke-width', 1)
        .attr('d', c_preys(d3.range(0, x_space.length, 1)));

        preys_marker = svg_pop
        .append('circle')
        .attr('r', 3)
        .attr('stroke', this.prey_color);

        phase_curve = svg_pop_phase
        .append('path')
        .attr('stroke', this.phase_curve_color)
        .attr('stroke-width', 1)
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('d', c_phase(d3.range(0, x_space.length, 1)));
        phase_marker = svg_pop_phase
            .append('circle')
            .attr('r', 3)
            .attr('stroke', this.phase_curve_color);
            
        const dur = 10000
        svg_pop
        .transition()
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .duration(dur)
        .tween(null, function () {
            return function (t) {
                const i = Math.round(t * x_space.length - 1);
                const x = xScale(x_space[i]);
                
                predators_marker.attr('cx', x);
                predators_marker.attr('cy', yScale(predators[i]));
                preys_marker.attr('cx', x);
                preys_marker.attr('cy', yScale(preys[i]));

                phase_marker.attr('cx', xScale_phase(preys[i]));
                phase_marker.attr('cy', yScale_phase(predators[i]));
            };
        });

      bottomAxis = svg_pop
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
      bottomAxis
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'axis-title')
        .attr('y', 25)
        .attr('dy', '.71em')
        .attr('x', (width + margin.left) / 2)
        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
        .attr('fill', 'black')
        .text('Tiempo');

      leftAxis = svg_pop.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
      leftAxis
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'axis-title')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        .attr('y', -30)
        .attr('dy', '.71em')
        .attr('x', -(height - margin.bottom) / 2)
        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
        .attr('fill', 'black')
        .text('Densidad');

      bottomAxis_phase = svg_pop_phase
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale_phase));
      bottomAxis_phase
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'axis-title')
        .attr('y', 25)
        .attr('dy', '.71em')
        .attr('x', (width + margin.left) / 2)
        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
        .attr('fill', 'black')
        .text('Densidad presa');

      leftAxis_phase = svg_pop_phase
        .append('g')
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale_phase));
      leftAxis_phase
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'axis-title')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        .attr('y', -35)
        .attr('dy', '.71em')
        .attr('x', -(height - margin.bottom) / 2)
        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
        .attr('fill', 'black')
        .text('Densidad predador');
      diag_phase = svg_pop_phase
        .append('line')
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('stroke-width', 1)
        .attr('stroke-dasharray', '5,5')
        .attr('x1', xScale_phase(yDomain[0]))
        .attr('y1', yScale_phase(yDomain[0]))
        .attr('x2', xScale_phase(yDomain[1]))
        .attr('y2', yScale_phase(yDomain[1]));
    },
  };
  prey_predator.draw_graph();
</script>



